# Showing that a matrix is singular

Tags: matrices, determinant

Consider a matrix $A$ of dimension $4\times 4$ 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1} & a_2 & a_3 & a_4\\
0     & 0   & 0   & 0  \\
0     & 0   & 0   & 0  \\
0     & 0   & 0   & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
such that $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=1$ and $0\leq a_i\leq 1$ $\forall i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$.

Could you help me to show that this matrix is not invertible? In case the proof is too long, an intuition of the argument would be sufficient.

Comment: Calculate the determinant, it's zero.

Comment: Hint: If the determinant of a matrix is 0, the matrix is not invertible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an upper triangular matrix, so you can trivially calculate the determinant by multiplying the diagonals, which gives you a determinant of 0 meaning the matrix is non-invertible.

Comment: Or you could notice that any matrix that contains a zero row (or column) has determinant 0. This follows from the much more basic fact that swapping rows or columns changes the sign of the determinant.